# What should I do if I want to edit a part of my question that was blockquoted in an answer?

Tags: support, edits

If I have a question with a given sentence, an answer might include the sentence in a blockquote to respond to it specifically. However, the sentence is not as well said as it could be and I would like to edit it. I would like to improve the question, but I would also like to not invalidate (parts of) the existing answer.

What should I do?

Comment: You're talking about improving the grammar or using clearer terms or something similar, right?

Comment: @BSMP Sometimes yes the changes could be minor but other times I might want to rewrite a new sentence that conveys the idea better.

Answer (score 1):

> the sentence is not as well said as it could be and I would like to edit it

This sounds like a grammar change. If the existing answer is great and helps, then try not to edit that sentence. You can notify the answerer by commenting under their answer to notify the change if any though, especially if the suggested edits queue is full. But your best option is to **suggest an edit**.

If it is a significant change that happens to slightly invalidate some stuff in your question and the answer, please edit it asap to ensure clarity (especially if you realised you wrote something wrong), and notify the answerer immediately/suggest edit.

Comment: Why not just suggest an edit?